# Display of html contents in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, itext

I want to display PDF to HTML contents parallel. For the conversion I used `iTextSharp` from PDF to HTML. The HTML contents are in a format like:

```
<span style="background: cyan">NLJJCN+BellMT</span>
<span style="background: cyan">11.353696472168pt</span>
```

so I tried with div to display the contents it was overlapping .. then label same problem as div. At last I tried HTMLeditor

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtb_output" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine" width=" 493px" height=" 485px" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtb_output"></asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

but in this it was not taking style .. normally text was displayed. Can anyone please help me how can I display the HTMLcontents in the browser. I am working on web application.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I did not misunderstand, you have some html and you just want to show it on the browser from code-behind? If it is so, you can place a `Literal` control with `Mode="PassThrough"` and assign its `Text` property from code-behind. e.g.

**aspx markup:**

```
<asp:Literal ID="lt" Mode="PassThrough" runat="server" />
```

**code-behind:**

```
//...

lt.Text = "<span style='background-color:red'>It works!</span>";
```